# Test if a react component's child is in fact the provided child with jest

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I have a [react](https://facebook.github.io/react/) "wrapper" component that is supposed to wrap its child. Here is the relevant part:

```
export class Wrapper extends Component {   
    render(){
        return (<div>{ this.props.children }</div>);
    }
}
```

I am trying to use [`jest`](https://facebook.github.io/jest/) to test if the rendered child is indeed what has been provided to this wrapper.
Here is what I tried;

```
describe('SwapWrapper', () => {
    it('contains its child', () => {
        const potentialChild = (<AMockedComponent/>);
        const wrapper = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
            <Wrapper>{potentialChild}</Wrapper>
        );
        const realChild = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(wrapper, AMockedComponent);
        expect(realChild).toBe(potentialChild); // Obviously does not work.
    });
});
```

It obviously does not work. [`realChild` is a component instance while `potentialChild` is a component element](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html).

Currently, the only things I have been able to do is to create `potentialChild` with a property and to check that `realChild` does contain this property.

Is there a more valid way to check if `realChild` corresponds in fact to the `potentialChild` that has been provided?

Comment: That does not work because it's not the same instance. If you want to test if it's the correct type of component, just test the equality between `type` properties : `expect(realChild.type).toBe(AMockedComponent)`

Comment: The thing is I do not only want to check if it is the correct type. I want to be sure it corresponds *exactly* to the element that is provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution using [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html).
The [`ref`](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) property of a react element will be called back with the created instance when it is instantiated.

```
describe('SwapWrapper', () => {
    it('contains its child', () => {
        const ref = jest.fn();
        const potentialChild = (<AMockedComponent ref={ref}/>);
        const wrapper = TestUtils.renderIntoDocument(
            <Wrapper>{potentialChild}</Wrapper>
        );
        const realChild = TestUtils.findRenderedComponentWithType(wrapper, AMockedComponent);
        expect(ref).toBeCalledWith(realChild);
    });
});
```